# Is there a way to replicate pressing the enter key in one terminal from another?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, enter

I have a script that runs a program that generates an email and then waits for the user to input information from that email. Because of this, the information is not available to pipe to the program on execution.  It has to be done after it's running already.

I've tried a number of the different method suggestions, redirecting to the terminal (echo or cat > /dev/pts/#), mkfifo, expect, etc.  Most of these methods are successful in actually sending the information to the target terminal - I actually see the information show up there.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to send the equivalent of someone pressing the enter key.

Newline (using echo -en) or \n inside of the information send actually makes the cursor move in the target terminal - but it's not the same as actually pressing enter.  It just scrolls the screen down one line.  If I select the terminal window and press enter, it then accepts the input.

How can I do this from a different terminal (or can I?)

Or better yet, is there a way from the same script that's launched the program now waiting for input to send the program input?

Most of what I've seen has gone the route of using another terminal to try to send the information to the program.

**Flow:**

Simple similar example is if you were running a shell script that during its execution, runs a program that generates a PIN sent to your email, and then waits for the PIN to be entered before continuing.

In terminal 1, a bash script is run - one of the steps this script does is launch a program that generates an email and then sits at a prompt, waiting for the user to provide input (data from the email sent).

In terminal 2 (or if you can do this through terminal 1 somehow), take the value from the email and input it to the program in terminal 1, including pressing the enter key, so the program sees this value as actually entered and the program can complete its execution.

script in terminal 1:

```
...
if [ -f $progamToRun ]; then  
    $programToRun    # This program sends the email and prompts the user for information from the email. It waits here...  
    # once information from email is entered, continue executing commands here
fi
```

script in terminal 2:

```
...
# monitor email  
# retrieve information from email
# send information to program in terminal 1 that is waiting for this input
# exit script
```

The steps for the script in terminal 2 are working - and all of the methods I've tried to send the information to the program in terminal 1 haven't worked - that is to say, even if the information appears in the terminal through STDIN, etc. the application running doesn't recognize it as input so it's still sitting in the wait state.

I attempted to use netcat as suggested, but that's failing differently.

In terminal 1 I ran:

```
cat /tmp/nctest | /tmp/docl.sh -i 2>&1 | nc -l 127.0.0.1 8080 > /tmp/nctest
```

docl.sh contains one line, the application I am running to generate the email and wait.

In terminal 2 I ran:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8080 <information from email>
```

When I run this in terminal 2, I immediately get the error from the program run in the script in terminal 1 that it failed. I tried this:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8080
```

by itself to see if there was an issue passing the information on the same line I run nc, but get the same result. It's like the first terminal's nc command actually runs the application and then somehow bypasses or processes the prompt, so it's gone before I can enter the information from the email.

I also tried the command in terminal 1 without the -i and without the 2>&1, but there was no difference in the result.

Comment: Why would a different terminal accept the input? How would it know when the user is done typing? The user should press enter when they're ready

Comment: A **small** test case of code will generate better help than your current description (IMHO).  I assume you've already spent a lot of time on this and you are impatient to get it done, but focus on the simplest version of this problem that then be enhanced to provide the result you need. Update your Q with specific instructions "do these 2-3 lines on machine 1", "do this on machine 2" so we can better understand your problem. Good luck.

Comment: And recall that inputs and outputs are tied to processes. Just because you can see data appear on the terminal of a remote machine, doesn't mean that any (but the terminal process) is actually reading that data.

Comment: It looks like you'd be better off setting up a listener of some kind, I think I understand what you're trying to achieve but I see no reason to do so in the fashion you describe.

Comment: Seems like you nee to be looking into using netcat.

Comment: @ElanHamburger - I've simplified what I'm trying to do - the goal is to have this done by a bash script - not a person entering it in one terminal vs. another. I will add that to the posting so that's more clear.

Comment: @shellter - yes, I've tried named pipes and writing to the stdin of the process (/proc/$PID/fd/0) but that's had the same results as the other scenarios I've mentioned.

Comment: again, some real code  please. As is, this Q deserves (IMHO) to be voted-closed as "too board" or "asking for a tutorial". Have you read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) ? If not, please do. Good luck.

Comment: @RamanSailopal - Thanks for the suggestion.  I am trying this as a solution - but this has the opposite problem for me.  The script running the program is not waiting for input, so when I try to send input to it through netcat and the port, it fails because it's already completed.

Comment: Why do you need a second terminal at all? Let your program run and send its Email, then read the required input form Terminal 1 afterwards.

Comment: I was finally able to resolve my issue by using screen and a combination of suggestions from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen
https://askubuntu.com/questions/356006/kill-a-screen-session
https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi

Comment: @MarkSetchell The script just sits in terminal 1 waiting, and there was no way (that I could see) to get the information from the email and enter it from the same terminal session. So I had to have a second instance that got the information from the email and entered back into the terminal with the waiting application.